# Call stored procedure for each XML element without cursors

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-openxml

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSendLogLinesAsXML]
(
    @device_id varchar(128),
    @application_name VARCHAR(64),
    @application_user_name VARCHAR(6),
    @log_lines_xml XML
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
    @ixml INT,
    @log_line_dt DATETIME,
    @log_line_message varchar(max)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @ixml OUTPUT,
    @log_lines_xml

SELECT @log_line_dt = dt,
    @log_line_message = data
FROM OPENXML(@ixml, '/lines/line', 3) WITH (
        dt DATETIME,
        data varchar(max)
        )   

--I want to do the following for each line element      
EXEC spSendLogLine
    @device_id = @device_id,
    @application_name = @application_name,
    @application_user_name = @application_user_name,
    @log_line_dt = @log_line_dt,
    @log_line_message = @log_line_message   

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @ixml

return -100

END
```

I call the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[spSendLogLinesAsXML]
     @device_id = N'devid123',
     @application_name = N'CJA App 1',
     @application_user_name = N'anatoli',
     @log_lines_xml = '<lines><line><dt>2013-03-01T13:00:00</dt><data>Something happened and it was logged</data></line><line><dt>2013-03-01T13:01:00</dt><data>Oh my god the building is burning and people are dying</data></line></lines>'
```

How can I modify my stored procedure to call spSendLogLine for each line element?

Edit: According to [SQL - Call Stored Procedure for each record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077948/sql-call-stored-procedure-for-each-record) cursors are bad. So I want to know a better way. I don't mind how much my stored procedure is changed to achieve this, as long as it ends up working properly and is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSendLogLinesAsXML]
(
    @device_id varchar(128),
    @application_name VARCHAR(64),
    @application_user_name VARCHAR(6),
    @log_lines_xml XML
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @log_line_dt datetime,
        @log_line_message varchar(1024)

declare @curse cursor 
set @curse = cursor fast_forward for 
select n.d.value('dt[1]', 'datetime') as log_line_dt, n.d.value('data[1]', 'varchar(1024)') as log_line_message
from @log_lines_xml.nodes('/lines/line') n(d)

open @curse

fetch next from @curse into @log_line_dt, @log_line_message

while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    EXEC spSendLogLine
        @device_id = @device_id,
        @application_name = @application_name,
        @application_user_name = @application_user_name,
        @log_line_dt = @log_line_dt,
        @log_line_message = @log_line_message   

    fetch next from @curse into @log_line_dt, @log_line_message
end

close @curse;

return -100
END
GO
```

Comment: But everyone at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077948/sql-call-stored-procedure-for-each-record seems to think cursors are bad

Comment: @cja: either you can rewrite your stored procedure so it can handle multiple input parameters - then you can avoid a cursor - or then you have to live with the evilness and uglyness of cursors in T-SQL ....

Comment: My question was "How can I modify my stored procedure..." I'm happy to change it. I don't want to learn something if it's evil and ugly. I want to know the best way of doing it.

Comment: Cursors can be bad when they are used to do the same thing as a select, such as doing an aggregation, etc.. However, sometimes, they are necessary, like in your case, were you want to *iterate* and run some operation on each iteration.

Comment: @marc_s how do I "rewrite [my] stored procedure so it can handle multiple input parameters"?

Comment: Seriously, there's not always a problem using a cursor :) What do you think app developers do when they get a resultset back in .NET or Java?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, following muhmud's answer. Still wish someone would tell me how to do it sans cursors.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSendLogLinesAsXML] 
(
    @device_id VARCHAR(128),
    @application_name VARCHAR(64),
    @application_user_name VARCHAR(6),
    @log_lines_xml XML
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ixml INT,
    @log_line_dt DATETIME,
    @log_line_message VARCHAR(max),
    @cursor CURSOR

SET @cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR

SELECT n.d.value('dt[1]', 'datetime') AS log_line_dt,
    n.d.value('data[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS log_line_message
FROM @log_lines_xml.nodes('/lines/line') n(d)

OPEN @cursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM @cursor
INTO @log_line_dt,
    @log_line_message

WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC spSendLogLine @device_id = @device_id,
        @application_name = @application_name,
        @application_user_name = @application_user_name,
        @log_line_dt = @log_line_dt,
        @log_line_message = @log_line_message

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @cursor
    INTO @log_line_dt,
        @log_line_message
END

RETURN - 100
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer, you could do something like this:

1. define a **user-defined table type** that holds all the columns that are relevant to your procedure:

   ```
   CREATE TYPE dbo.SendLogLineType 
        AS TABLE (LineDate DATETIME2(3), LineData VARCHAR(200), DeviceID VARCHAR(128), 
                  ApplicationName VARCHAR(64), AppUserName VARCHAR(6) )
   ```
2. then, extract your lines into that table, and add the other "fixed" parameters (this happens inside your `[spSendLogLinesAsXML]` procedure):

   ```
   DECLARE @InputTable dbo.SendLogLineType

   INSERT INTO @InputTable(LineDate, LineData, DeviceID, ApplicationName, AppUserName)
      SELECT
         XLine.value('(dt)[1]', 'DATETIME2'),
         XLine.value('(data)[1]', 'varchar(200)'), 
         @device_id,
         @application_name,
         @application_user_name
      FROM     
         @log_lines_xml.nodes('/lines/line') AS XTbl(XLine)
   ```
3. and lastly, change your `spSendLogLine` procedure to accept a **table valued parameter** of that defined table type and change its logic so that it will iterate over all rows that get passed into it:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE spSendLogLine
       (@SendLogLineData dbo.SendLogLineType READONLY)
   AS
   BEGIN
       -- iterate over all rows in @SendLogLineData and send out those e-mails!
   END
   ```

Read more about Table-Valued Parameters on the [relevant MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't you need a cursor to do that iteration where you're sending out the emails? I suppose you would call `spSendLogLine` without having to use one ...

Comment: How do I iterate over a "table valued parameter" ?

Comment: @Cja: just like you *iterate* over a table - use `SELECT` etc.

Comment: It seems to me this answer doesn't solve the problem: the question is "how do you iterate", but this answer is just a "you split the xml in a table, then you iterate". Ok. How?