# How to pass certain values from a table to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my problem. I have a table `tbl_archivos` with values like this:

```
Id   desc    namerc
---------------------------
1    arch1   RC201721091701
2    arch2   RC201724091701
```

I have to pass all the **values** of the column `namerc` in my table (above) to a stored procedure like parameter.

Like this :

```
sp_runproceess_billing 'RC201721091701'
```

and then the another value `RC201724091701`.

I am not allowed to use a cursor!

Please help me with this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Your google search string is `sq server table value parameters`.

Comment: If sp_runproceess_billing can be refactored as a user function you can call it directly within the select, failing that see [SQL Call Stored Procedure for each Row without using a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656804/sql-call-stored-procedure-for-each-row-without-using-a-cursor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this solution

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE(id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, namerc VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @t 
    SELECT DISTINCT namerc FROM tbl_archivos
    ORDER BY tbl_archivos
    DECLARE @index INT = 1
    DECLARE @max INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)
    DECLARE @current_namerc VARCHAR(50)
    WHILE @index <= @max
    BEGIN
       SELECT @current_namerc  = namerc FROM @t WHERE id = @index
       EXEC sp_runproceess_billing @current_namerc
       SET @index = @index + 1
    END
```

Comment: Kind of cheating because you're just replacing a cursor with a while loop which has the same performance impact...but I was going to suggest the same thing. If you're restricted from using cursors because "my boss heard they were bad", then try using a while loop instead. Just don't tell her!