# Execute stored procedure in a loop for set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreach

I want to write a stored procedure to loop through set of records and for each of the record execute another stored procedure.

Select query returning list of id's:

```
select id 
from abc 
where some condition
```

I have a stored procedure `usp_get_data @id=id` which I want to execute for each of the rows of the select query. I do not want to use cursor. What are the other ways I can achieve this?

```
foreach(item in select statement)
{
    execute stored procedure
}
```

The sub stored procedure will return a list of records which I will then return back from the main stored procedure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Call Stored Procedure for each Row without using a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656804/sql-call-stored-procedure-for-each-row-without-using-a-cursor)

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You know a loop is not really that much different from a cursor? What reason do you have for not using a cursor?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, because cursors take up memory and create locks.

Comment: @bendataclear here in my case id will not be sequential, so I don't this I can use similar query as answered for the post you tagged.

Comment: @Arti You mean you need it to run asynchronously?

Comment: @Arti so does a loop that reads from a table every iteration

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to use cursor. What are the other ways I can achieve this?

Rewirte the stored procedure to operate over a set of data. You can pass bulk data to a stored procedure using a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15), or by loading data into a Temp table, which the stored procedure then uses.

Or use a cursor.  They aren't the worst thing, and "calling a stored procedure for each row" is probably the most common legitimate use of a cursor.  Also the looping-without-a-cursor solutions are all dumb and worse than using a cursor.

Comment: Another option, depending on what the sproc does, is to write it as a table-valued function that can be `CROSS APPLY`'d. This isn't always possible, but often overlooked.

Comment: If cursors were as bad as some people believe, they would not have been implemented!

Comment: Also cursors are old.  They are basically the same as they were 25 years ago, when servers ran single-core 100MHz processors.  What was "too slow" then is hardly relevant any more.