# SQL - Execute stored procedure for all values in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL stored procedure **'A'** which validates certain bank account information for a given account and it accepts the account number as an argument **'arg1'**

I want to execute the procedure for all values present in **Column X** of another table **XXX** (all bank Accounts present in the Accounts table)

I am not sure if something like this would work

```
exec A @arg1 = X from XXX
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of "A"? It sounds like you are attempting to cursor which is generally a no no. Can you give more detail of what your pre/post data is/should be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656804/sql-call-stored-procedure-for-each-row-without-using-a-cursor

Comment: See if the TVF+CROSS APPLY helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477064/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-over-a-set-without-using-a-cursor

Comment: What kinf of a condition to the passing value been used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No there isn't a bulk EXEC the way you want to run it.

Option 1: Generate and run by hand. Copy result, paste back into SSMS and execute.

```
select 'exec A @arg1 = ' + quotename(X,'''') + ';'
from XXX
```

Option 2: Generate a batch and run using dynamic SQL.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = '';
select @sql = @sql + 'exec A @arg1 = ' + quotename(X,'''') + ';'
from XXX;
exec (@sql);
```

Option 3: Run it in a loop

```
declare @x varchar(max);
select top(1) @x = X from xxx where X is not null order by X;
while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    exec sp_executesql N'exec A @arg1=@x;', N'@x varchar(max)', @x=@x;
    select top(1) @x = X from xxx where X > @x order by X;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, the loop solution does what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

It's generally better to approach things in a set-based way, but if you really do need to do something sequentially for each row in a result set, here's how you can use a cursor:

```
declare cur cursor for
select X from XXX

declare @x int
open cur
fetch next from cur into @x

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    exec A @x

    fetch next from cur into @x
END
```

Comment: I need to do the same thing: run a stored proc on a value from every row in a table. what is a way to think about that in a set-based way?

Comment: @akh2103 It really depends on what your sproc does. You may be able to rewrite it to be set based with a correlated update, delete, or insert. If it has variables, replace those with table variables. Or it might not be feasible or worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the dynamic query with Coalesce command. Below query executes A stored procedure on data of X column of XXX table.

```
-- Create Dynamic Query
DECLARE @ValidateAccountCommand VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @ValidateAccountCommand = COALESCE(@ValidateAccountCommand + 
                                            '; EXEC A ', 
                                             'EXEC A ') 
                                + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,XxxData.X)
FROM 
(SELECT X FROM XXX) XxxData

PRINT @ValidateAccountCommand
EXECUTE (@ValidateAccountCommand)
```