# SQL Iterate my parameter to a stored procedure Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that will return an Integer. Many times the below query will return multiple IDs.

```
DECLARE @ID INT;

SELECT @ID = Id
        FROM MyTable
```

I then have to execute a pre made stored procedure that accepts that Id. The Stored Procedure is setup to take one Id at a time (I can't change it to make a list). How can I get the stored procedure to iterate over the entire list of IDs Returned?

```
exec storedProc @ID
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code won't work on most products.

Comment: @Jarlh Microsoft SSMS

Comment: @Dev101684 Consider, by analogy, that jarlh just asked you what model of car you drive, and you just responded with "unleaded gasoline".

Comment: @jarlh my apologies if i misunderstood, its a relational database using Microsoft SQL Server, thanks for your willingness to to help!

Comment: If you cannot change your procedure you will have to execute it for each ID in a loop, aka cursor.

Comment: @Dev101684. No problem, we are all here to learn!

Comment: @Stu great idea! the cursor worked i'll give credit it you'd like to add as the answer

Comment: @Stu A (lightweight) `WHILE` loop with variables is probably better than a heavy `CURSOR` though ([c.f.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477064/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-over-a-set-without-using-a-cursor))

Comment: @Dai I would agree and would always choose that myself, I've never needed anything more complicated, I only mention cursor as that's how its commonly referred to - the easiest approach is to populate a #temptable, check rows exist as a loop condition and then assign an ID to a local variable in the loop, do stuff and delete it from the #temptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

Add new column 'Processed' tinyint with default value as zero on your table, to hold processed flag (assume: 0 - New, 1 - Successfully processed, 2 - Error ).
Iterate each unprocessed records where Processed=0 (new), get ID value and execute the stored procedure by passing the ID.
After the execution of stored procedure, update processed as 1. If any error, set processed = 2.

```
DECLARE @ID INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @ID = Id  FROM MyTable
WHERE Processed = 0
    
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT<>0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        EXEC storedProc @ID

        UPDATE MyTable SET Processed = 1 
        WHERE ID = @ID
                    
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @ID ID, ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrMsg
        
        UPDATE MyTable SET Processed = 2 -- Error 
        WHERE ID = @ID
    END CATCH

-- Get Next record
SELECT TOP 1 @ID = Id  FROM MyTable
WHERE Processed = 0

End  -- While..end
```