# Easy way to write a string with control characters to an nvarchar field in a DB?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net, textbox, multiline

**EDIT**:  Accepted answer points out what my issue was.  I added another answer which shows an even easier way.

I have a multiline textbox from which I create a single string:

```
    Dim wholeThing As String
    Dim line as String 
    For Each line In txtMultiline.Lines
        wholeThing = wholeThing & line & Environment.Newline
    Next
```

What I'd like to do is write this to a DB as-is by adding wholeThing as a parameter using to SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue, but all of my painstakingly-inserted newlines go away (or appear to).

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string) and was hoping I didn't need to concern myself with CHAR(nnn) SQL stuff.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean when you say "appears to"? A newline character can be easily stored in an `nvarchar` field.  What tools are you using to verify the results of your actions?

Comment: Hah ... OK, only the first line shows up in Access 2007, but they're all there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's even easier than this.  As per the discussion in the accepted answer, I wasn't seeing all of the lines in my view.  Putting up a messagebox showed everything.

What's more, I don't need to take things line by line:

```
wholeThing = txtMultiline.Text
```

works, too, and it keeps all of the line breaks.