# How to insert new line to nvarchar using c# code

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a field ,description nvarchar(200).

I am inserting  string with a lot of lines.

When I take quick watch over the string in visual studio,
I can see the string splited  over mutile lines as i expected.

line1 
line2 
line3

But when I insert to database using a stored procedure,all "\n\r" beomes just spaces.
When I read from the databse there is no "\n\r"

what can i do?

Comment: Is the stored procedure removing char #10 #3 and replacing them with spaces.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be stored just fine. When you look through SSMS, it removes the newlines for readability in its grid.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string/31174#31174)

> char(13) is CR. For DOS-/Windows-style CRLF linebreaks, you want char(13)+char(10), like:

```
'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHAR(13)`

Refer to: [CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa258239)

Answer (score 0):

its best to use `System.Environment.NewLine`