# How to carriage return C# string without \r\n?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my problem.

A user can enter text into a text area in the browser. Which is then emailed out to users.
What I want to know is that how do I handle carriage return? If I enter \r\n  for carriage return, the email (which is a plain text email) has actual \r\n in it.

In other words:

**On the SQL server end**

Case 1:
if I do this before the email gets sent
(notice the line break after line 1)

```
update emails
set
body='line 1
line 2'
where
id=100
```

**the email goes out correctly**

Case 2:

```
 update emails
 set
 body='line 1'+char(13) + char(10) +'line 2'
 where
 id=100
```

**This email also goes out correctly**

Case 3:
However if I do this

```
update emails
set
body='line 1 \r\n line 2',
where
id=100
```

**the email would have the actual text \r\n in it.**

How do I simulate case 1/2 through c# ?

Comment: Why in the world would you use UrlDecode? Are you decoding a URL?

Comment: You confused me when you said "replacing \r\n with enter". When you press enter, \r\n is generated.

Comment: As others have said, what are you expecting to get as a result? `\n` and/or `\r` IS a carriage return.

Comment: Can you explain better what you see in the emails? Do you literally see the text \r\n? If so, the problem isn't related to UrlDecode.

Comment: Why do you need to remove `%20`? Are you sending form data via `GET` rather than `POST`?

Comment: You're asking how to insert a carriage return into a string, but all the information you've given us indicates that it should be putting them in correctly.

Comment: Sorry guys, looks like I didn't explain correctly the first time. I edited my question, hopefully its clearer now.

Comment: How does the \r\n get into SQL in the first place? What exactly do you mean by "If I enter \r\n for carriage return"?

Comment: This question is very unclear even after edits. Based on the information provided it's very unlikely to ever help future visitors. As it is I'm voting close this as **too localized**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whatever c#'s string replace method is to replace `"\\r\\n"` with `"\r\n"` and that should fix it.

Answer (score 7):

SQL literals (at least those in SQL Server) *do not* support such escape sequences (although you *can* just hit enter within the string literal so that it spans multiple lines). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string) for some alternatives if writing it *as* an SQL string is a requirement.

**If running the SQL programmatically from C#, use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)** which will handle this just fine:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "update emails set body=@body where id=@id"
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", "line 1 \r\n line2");
```

Note that the handling of the *string literal* (and conversion of the `\r` and `\n` character escape sequences) *happens in C#* and the *value* (with CR and LF *characters*) is passed to SQL.

If the above didn't address the problem, keep reading.

---

[4.10.13 The textarea element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-textarea-element.html):

> For historical reasons, the element's value is normalised in three different ways for three different purposes. The raw value is the value as it was originally set. It is not normalized. The API value is the value used in the value IDL attribute. It is normalized so that line breaks use "LF" (U+000A) characters. Finally, there is the form submission value. *[Upon form submission the textarea] is normalized so that line breaks use U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF) character pairs*, and in addition, if necessary given the element's wrap attribute, additional line breaks are inserted to wrap the text at the given width.

Note that CR and LF represent *characters* and not the two-character sequence of `\` followed by either the `r` or `n` characters - this form is often found in *string literals*. If it appears as such then something is doing the incorrect conversion and *putting* (or *leaving*) the `\` there. Or, perhaps there is some misguided "add slashes" hack somewhere?

As pointed out, while URL decode is likely wrong, it won't directly do this conversion. However, if the conversion happened *previously* before being "URL Encoded", then it will (correctly) decode to (incorrect) values.

In either case, it's *a bug*. So find out *where* the incorrect data conversion is introduced and fix it (attach a debugger and/or monitor the network traffic for clues) - the required information to isolate where is simply not present in the post.