# php-mysql carriage returns

Tags: php, mysql, carriage-return

I am relatively new to php/mysql. I am trying to do carriage returns for this part:

```
echo "<td colspan='5'>" . nl2br($row['dish_description']) . "</td>";
```

"dish_description" contains some text which includes "\n" 
e.g. "Served with salad and mint sauce. \n Contains beef." In the MySQL database
however I cannot display the carriage return.

```
    <?php
    require_once 'login.php';
    $con = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database". mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dishes` ORDER BY `dishes`.`dish_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 200");

    echo '<table align="center">
    ';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='width: 60px'></td>";
    echo "<th style='width: 100px'>Dish No</th>";
    echo "<td style='width: 70px'>" . $row['dish_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<th style='width: 100px'>Dish Name</th>";
    echo "<td style='width: 120px'>" . $row['dish_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<th style='width: 120px'>Dish Price</th>";
    echo "<td>£" . $row['dish_price'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='width: 75px'></td>";
    echo "<th style='width: 100px'>Vegetarian</th>";
    echo "<td style='width: 70px'>" . $row['dish_vegetarian']   ."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px'></td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 70px'></td>";
    echo "<th style='width: 120px'>Contains Nuts</th>";
    echo "<td style='width: 120px'>" . $row['dish_nuts']   ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='width: 75px'></td>";
    echo "<th style='width: 100px'>Information</th>";
    ***echo "<td colspan='5'>" . nl2br($row['dish_description']) . "</td>";***
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr height='10px'>";
    echo "<td style='width: 75px'></td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you include the is_xhtml flag in your call to nl2br? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: I'm not too sure on how to use it. I'm somewhat new to php/mysql

Comment: Your problem is fixed now, but if you want, you could try replacing nl2br($row['dish_description']) with nl2br($row['dish_description'],true)

I'm not saying this was the cause.  I was just curious if it would happen to fix it.  It uses the more 'correct' <br /> instead of <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion if you `echo` it as HTML you can just add `<br>` tags to your records in database.

Comment: This would work, but I personally wouldn't want to store html in a sql database. What if other non-html applications want to show the data?

Comment: @MrVimes - you can use CR or LF like char(10) / char(13) . More info [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/22/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-insert-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed-in-code/) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string).