# Wrap text in SQL server using function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I googled a lot to wrap string with minimum defined length, but I am unable to get any solution.
I created my own function that can wrap text by given number of characters per line.
This post may help to others looking for same.

Comment: Phrase this as a ***question*** that your post answers.

Answer (score 0):

Function 1

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_BraekTextInLines]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @InString varchar(max), 
    @LineLength int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN


if @LineLength <=0 or @LineLength> LEN(@InString)
return @InString

declare @tmp varchar(max)
declare @result varchar(max)
DECLARE @word varchar (max);
declare @addedInResult bit
DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR SELECT s FROM SplitMax(@InString,'');

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @word;
--set @tmp =@word
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


  if LEN(@tmp + ' ' + @word) < @LineLength
  begin
    set @tmp = @tmp + ' ' + @word   
    set @addedInResult = 0
  end
  else
  begin

    set @result =  isnull(@result, ' ') + CHAR(13) +  RTRIM(LTRIM( @tmp))
    set @tmp = @word
    set @addedInResult = 1

  end

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @word;

    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
    begin
     set @result =  isnull(@result, ' ') + CHAR(13) + RTRIM(LTRIM( @tmp))
     set @addedInResult = 1
    end
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

if @addedInResult=0
begin
    set @result =  isnull(@result, ' ') + CHAR(13) +  RTRIM(LTRIM( @tmp))
end

return @result

END
```

Function 2

```
   Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_WrapString]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @InString varchar(max), 
    @LineLength int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

declare @result varchar(max)
declare @tmp varchar(max)
DECLARE @Line varchar (max);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR SELECT s FROM SplitMax(@InString,CHAR(13));

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Line;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  set @tmp = dbo.fn_BraekTextInLines(@Line,@LineLength)
  set @result = isnull(@result,' ') + @tmp

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Line;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

return Rtrim(Ltrim(@result))

END
```

Function 3

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitMax](@String VARCHAR(max), @Delimiter CHAR(1))       
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (s VARCHAR(max))       
AS       
BEGIN       
DECLARE @idx INT       
DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(max)        
SELECT @idx = 1       
IF len(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL  RETURN       
while @idx!= 0       
BEGIN       
SET @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
IF @idx!=0       
SET @slice = LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)       
ELSE       
SET @slice = @String       
IF(len(@slice)>0)  
INSERT INTO @temptable(s) VALUES(@slice)       
SET @String = RIGHT(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
IF len(@String) = 0 break       
END   
RETURN       
END
```

Calling Function fn_WrapString to wrap the text

```
declare @name varchar(max)
set @name = 'Ine was King of Wessex from 688 to 726. He was'+ CHAR(13) +'unable to retain the territorial gains of his predecessor, Cædwalla, who had brought much of southern England under his'
print dbo.fn_WrapString(@name,60)
```

Output :

```
Ine was King of Wessex from 688 to 726. He was 
unable to retain the territorial gains of his predecessor,
Cædwalla, who had brought much of southern England under
his
```

Comment: is this answer to your `own` question ?

Answer (score 0):

I also created a short version for warping the text in T-Sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WrapText]
(
    @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @length INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @result = CASE
                         WHEN @result IS NULL THEN
                             SUBSTRING(@List, number.Number - @length + 1, @length)
                         ELSE
                             @result + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + SUBSTRING(@List, number.Number - @length + 1, @length)
                     END
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
        FROM sys.all_objects
    ) number
    WHERE number.Number <= LEN(@List) + @length - 1
          AND number.Number % @length = 0;

    RETURN @result;
END;
```

Calling Function:

```
SELECT dbo.WrapText('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',5)
```

If you are coping the result from grid, it will not past with line breaks as explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59189881/1606054