# How do I store text in database with line breaks or paragraph

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

In my application I have Terms for Apps. Before I used to put this in front-end with HTML .

But now I need to put this text in database in a column called **AppTerms** inside table called **App**.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string) link in stackoverflow and followed like this :

```
UPDATE [AppsDatabase].[dbo].[App]
SET AppTerms = 'This App has no minimum term.' + CHAR(13) +
'This App is built and is supported through the standard way of using the company online support.' + CHAR(13) +
'Incorrectly formatted data will not be formatted but may be charged for.'
 WHERE AppID = 8
 GO
```

But I am not getting line breaks here. And also can someone tell me how can i put bullet points in each line?

Comment: Can you paste the output of this command? `DECLARE @Terms NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT AppTerms FROM AppsDatabase.dbo.App WHERE AppID = 8;); PRINT @Terms;`

Comment: @IainElder When I used your command, I can see text formatted with line breaks in output window. So I think I am doing mistake in front end. When I am calling this, text is not formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are showing HTML you need to store `</br>` instead of CHAR(13).

Displaying this text in HTML will yield the correct display. In addition you can wrap a paragraph in `<p>...</p>`.

For bullet lists look at http://www2.gol.com/users/billp/articlehtml/bullet.html.

This is under the assumption that you take the text out and display in HTML.

Comment: but if i use </br>, it shows incorrect syntax error. I tried to use like this : + </br> +

Comment: The </br> needs to be part of the text - HTML will then convert it into a line break. It is not possible to show the text in SQL with line breaks - this would require adding the CHAR(13) which is ignored by HTML.

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late, yet, I had the same problem... 
The solution I came up with is to store paragraphs(or lists... or whatever) in a separate child table and handle the formatting at the server programming language level.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. In HTML you could use the `</br>` tag.

Comment: I had trouble with displaying the db-tag but now the suggested answer should be visible.

Comment: I was referring to "It should work.  What datatype is your column?"  That doesn't belong in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want the application to render HTML with line breaks, but you're storing plain text.

You need to store HTML instead. Encode the line breaks using the [`<br>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) element.

Try this:

```
UPDATE [AppsDatabase].[dbo].[App]
SET AppTerms = 'This App has no minimum term.<br>' + CHAR(13) +
'This App is built and is supported through the standard way of using the company online support.<br>' + CHAR(13) +
'Incorrectly formatted data will not be formatted but may be charged for.'
 WHERE AppID = 8;
```

If you want to encode bullet points, check out the [`<ul>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) and  [`<li>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) elements.

This is a data formatting issue more than a SQL Server issue. You would have had the same problem if you tried to store the data in a file instead of a table.

The [W3C specification for HTML Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html) explains how white space is handled in HTML:

> In HTML, only the following characters are defined as white space
>   characters:
>
> - ASCII space (`&#x0020;`)
> - ASCII tab (`&#x0009;`)
> - ASCII form feed (`&#x000C;`)
> - Zero-width space (`&#x200B;`)
>
> Line breaks are also white space characters.
>
> [...] user agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing output inter-word space.

Line breaks are equivalent to spaces, and multiple white space characters are collapsed to a single space in the output.