# Create a new line in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new line in sql server.  This is my query

```
UPDATE Translations
SET FieldLabel = 'Sequence' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Number'
WHERE (id = '1')
```

I need there to be a break between Sequence and Number.  So far nothing is working.

Its generated on the page using

```
@Html.LabelFor(p => Model.FirstOrDefault().SeqNbr, htmlAttributes: null,
 labelText: xxx.Controllers.FieldTranslation.GetLabel("SeqNbr", 
@xxx.DNetSynch.GlobalVariables.LanguageID))
```

Does not return the break whether i use char(10) or `br`

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line break will not show up in the result grid but it's there. You can try copy & paste the cell to a text editor.

Comment: It doesn't display it as such when I reference it from the database in my site

Comment: So is it not showing up on your website or you can't see it in the database? if the first case, I suggesting adding `<br/>` instead of `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`. That's HTML for line break. If the second case, there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

This will work, but you FieldLabel must be a varchar() or nvarchar()

```
UPDATE       Translations
SET                FieldLabel = 'Sequence' + CHAR(10) + 'Number'
WHERE        (id = '1')
```

if you render this in a web page, then use

```
UPDATE       Translations
SET                FieldLabel = 'Sequence<br>Number'
WHERE        (id = '1')
```

but it would be better to use the first solution, and do a replace of `char(10)` by a `<br>` in your server logic.

Comment: the <br> is rendered as plaintext inside of a `<label>`