# SQL: Insert a linebreak in varchar string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've searched StackOverflow for all the possible solutions concerning how to insert a linebreak in a SQL text string. I've referred this link but to no avail. [How to insert a line break in a SQL Server VARCHAR/NVARCHAR string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string)

But none of the solutions are working for me.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
insert into sample (dex, col) 
values (2, 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.')
```

But this is the output generated: (Select Col from sample where dex = 2)

> This is line 1.  This is line 2.

This is the output that I desire:

> This is line 1.
>   This is line 2.

I'm using SQL server and SSMS if that helps.

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: If you're running it from within SQL Management Studio, it won't display that way, probably, because of the limitations on the way the data is presented in the system. If you copy and paste it to somewhere else, it will be on two lines.

Comment: len(col) will have the CR LF

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well your query works perfectly fine.
SSMS by default shows all query out put in the grid view, which does not display the line break character.

To see it you can switch to text view using <kbd>`cntrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`T`</kbd> shortcut or like below

[image]

The results I got for your query are below( and they work)
[image]

Answer (score 11):

It works perfectly:

```
CREATE TABLE sample(dex INT, col VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO sample(dex, col) 
VALUES (2, 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.');

SELECT *
FROM sample;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/ZEOLW44315)**</kbd>

Output:

[image]

The "problem" is `SSMS` grid view that skips newline characters (and others too). Otherwise you will get different rows height like in `Excel`.

---

You could observe the same behaviour in `SEDE`.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo-SEDE`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471156)**</kbd><kbd>**[`LiveDemo-SEDE-TextView`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471158?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Output:

[image]

[image]

---

You could compare it using:

```
SELECT 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.';
PRINT  'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.';
```

Answer (score 6):

The CR/LF chars are there, it's just that in the format of your output, they are being ignored.

I've created a fiddle to illustrate this, with 2 `VARCHAR` columns. In the first one I insert the text with no `CR/LF`, in the second I include them

```
CREATE TABLE sample (dex INT, colnocr VARCHAR(50), col VARCHAR(50)) ;
insert into sample (dex, colnocr, col) values 
(2, 
 'This is line 1.' + 'This is line 2.',
 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
)
;
```

if you run the query

```
SELECT * FROM sample
```

The result **in plain text** are:

```
| dex |                        colnocr |                              col |
|-----|--------------------------------|----------------------------------|
|   2 | This is line 1.This is line 2. | This is line 1.
This is line 2. |
```

but if you run it in **tabular** :

```
dex     colnocr                                                     col
2       This is line 1.This is line 2.      This is line 1. This is line 2.
```

Check it : <kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94a9b/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to this discussion, but in SSMS 2016, there is an option on the Tools | Options menu under Query Results / SQL Server / Results to Grid called "Retain CR/LF on copy or save".  Checking this box will allow you to copy values from a cell in a grid result to, say, another query window and still have the line breaks.

Comment: I had to restart SSMS 2017 in order for this option to take effect.

Comment: This was the ticket. No restart of SSMS required for me. Definitely was not working without it.