# T-SQL multi-line strings without indent chars

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This seems simple...

How do you store a multi-line string so your code stays nicely formatted.

Doing this is ugly

```
DECLARE @myStr NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @myStr = 'This represents a really long
string that i need multiple lines for,
dude.'
```

but the above results in the correct string output:

```
SELECT @myStr
'This represents a really long string that i need multiple lines for, dude.'
```

Doing this makes it easier to read my code:

```
DECLARE @myStr NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @myStr = 'This represents a really long
    string that i need multiple lines for,
    dude.'
```

but results in this:

```
SELECT @myStr
'This represents a really long     string that i need multiple lines for, 
dude.'
```

Is there some special way to escape tabs in a multiline string (like every other language has)..

Answer (score 17):

You're looking for a [backslash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-backslash?view=sql-server-2017) ("\"):

```
SET @myStr = 'This represents a really long \
    string that i need multiple lines for, \
    dude.'
```

Comment: Actually your example gives 2 spaces between 'long' and 'string' - you need to remove the space before the `\`.

Comment: And unfortunately it doesn't work if you use spaces instead of tabs - unless its a single space - which doesn't really achieve the desired effect :(

Comment: hmm, i'm not getting the desired effect. `'\'` seems to escape the line break, but no the indent at the front of the second line in the string.

Comment: Hmmm - I was afraid you might have had the *opposite* problem.  Plan B is to [concatenate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) your strings: `line 1 ' + 'line 2' + ...`  Please let us know if that helps.  One other note (if you want to add or retain linefeeds in your text string): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608252/

Comment: @JamieMarshall it does remove the first tab on the new line, if you are using the tab character.

Comment: @DaleBurrell maybe its because I tested putting the whole thing in an indented block?

Comment: Q1) How exactly do you *want* it to look?  One continuous line, with no extraneous spacing?  Q2) How does it appear using "\" (continuation lines), with the extraneous left-spacing on each line?  Q3) Does it appear differently if each continued line is flush-left?  Q4) Did you try "+" (concatentation)?  Any difference?  Q5) How are you displaying it?  With a SQL "select" in SSMS?  With a console-mode C# app?  Other?