# Concatenate Address field in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to concatenate a select stament for AddressLine1 up to AddressLine4, PostalCode and a PhoneNo columns in sql server 2008 such that each field will begin in a new line. This is to be use for reporting purposes. Which is the best way to have this done?

Desired outcome is:

```
    2 Jojo Street
    Kenyon Express Way
    Exeee
    UY19 78DF
    08945392847
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can use `+` to concatenate varchar columns. Newline would be `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`.

Comment: You need to do this in a reporting tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the required fields, and use the `char(13)+char(10)` in between them for a new line.

```
select AddressLine1 + char(13)+char(10)
       + AddressLine2 + char(13)+char(10)
       + AddressLine3   +char(13)+char(10)
       + AddressLine4 + char(13)+char(10)
       + PostalCode + char(13)+char(10)
       + PhoneNo
from table1
```

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. I used Abdul Rasheed solution. Charater return works but the returned lines are not in straight line with the first line on the address list. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Is there any blank space in front of the values?

Comment: Yes. There are blanck spaces

Answer (score 3):

You need to CONCAT the fields with the newline character of your target system, e.g. \n or CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string) could be helpful for you

Comment: upvoted for "of your target system", which is important to note.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

`select 'abc' + char(10) + 'def' + char(10) + 'ghi'`

In SQL Server Management Studio you will still see the string in one line, but if you copy the value to an editor, you will see that they are devided by linebreaks.

Comment: What if the target system/application requires CR+LF as line ending? Try pasting your result into Notepad vs Wordpad, for a simple example.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just typed down the windows way... and I did so when there were still no other answers - didn't intend to write duplicate answers.

Comment: but that's my point: this isn't "the windows way", since Windows nearly always uses CR+LF, as exemplified by Notepad's complete inability to handle other line endings (or almost any other task!)

Comment: strange... just performed the mentioned example on a windows environment and it worked fine. Same on an Oracle instance quite some time ago. Isn't it Linux / Unix which requires the double char linebreak?

Comment: No, it's quite the opposite. Windows uses CR+LF. Unix/Linux/etc use just LF. Well, FWIW, on Windows 7, with SQL 2008 R2 (I know...), running with Results to Grid doesn't invoke newlines in either editor, with either LF or CR+LF causing a space when copying/pasting. Putting Results to Text and pasting leads to a single line in Notepad and broken lines only in Wordpad (which is capable of handling LF-only endings). Querying with CR+LF to Text pastes properly into Notepad too. This might be somewhat version dependent, but the convention for Windows is to use CR+LF.

Comment: OK, thanks for this information! I see I have to get rid of old habbits. ;-)