# How to insert enters by script

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a powerhshell script who inserted values to the text column.
In my query command are something like this:

```
query = "UPDATE mytable 
SET mytable.mycolumn = 'FILE1
FILE2
FILE3
FILE4
FILE...
FROM mytable 
WHERE someconditions..."
```

When I select data form my database (after update above), I expected something like this:

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable

mycolumn
FILE1
FILE2
FILE3
FILE4
FILE...
```

But in database I have

```
mycolumn
FILE1            FILE2                 FILE3          FILE4         FILE...
```

When modify my query to:

```
query = "UPDATE mytable SET mytable.mycolumn = 'FILE1`r`n FILE2`r`nFILE3...
```

result is

```
FILE1`r`n FILE2`r`nFILE3...
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to concat them... so you expect your one row of data in that column to look like FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 as a string? Or are you wanting a row for every file name?

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Do you expect the attribute `mycolumn` for a _single tuple_ to contain all of the strings separated by newlines? Or do you expect _multiple tuples_, each of which has one of the strings in the attribute `mycolumn`?

Comment: In one row must be multiple valuses... as separator must be enter...

Comment: Have you tried using CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)   to add CR/LF

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string
And be sure to set your results to text versus grid to see this in action

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
query = "UPDATE mytable" + 
"SET mytable.mycolumn = 'FILE1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + " +
"'FILE2' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + " +
"'FILE3'  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + " +
"'FILE4'  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + " +
"'FILE'...  + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + " +
"FROM mytable " + 
"WHERE someconditions..."
```