# vb.net string concat adds vbCrlf literal to the string

Tags: asp.net, string, vb.net

I am trying to build a string that includes a newline character and is getting the weirdest result.  This string is going to be stored in a SQL database to be later used as part of an email.  My code is the following:

```
Dim strBody As String = "Andy," & Environment.NewLine
```

When I inspect the value of `strBody` during a debugging session, it is the following:

```
"Andy," & vbCrlf
```

I am obviously expecting is to be more like:

```
"Andy,"
```

Knowing that what is after the `,` is a hidden character.

Ultimately, the problem is...  when I include `strBody` as part of my SQL `insert` statement, it literally shows up as the following within my SQL `insert` statement:

```
'Andy," & vbCrLf & "'
```

I was using this code yesterday and it worked fine. I am using similar code within another function of the same asp.net project and it works fine.  I have tried using `+` instead of `&`, I have tried to use vbCrLf instead of `Environment.NewLine`, I have tried using `stringbuilder`, I have tried using `string.concat`.  All with the same results where the `& vbCrLf` is included in `strBody`.

Is there a setting that I accidentally changed?

I know this is a weird one...  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's literally impossible! If this is really true then you've broken the universe! -- Are you sure that it is _**really**_ part of the string? Have you tried writing it to a file or showing it in a message box? Keep in mind that what is shown when you inspect your variables in _**debug mode**_ is not the same as the final string.

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot showing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only Visual Studio showing you that there is new line character (vbCrLf or Environment.NewLine). If you use that string anywhere, it will be stored correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  After some investigation, I was able to confirm that Visual Studio displays the string like I mentioned above just so that the hidden characters are visible.  When it is actually stored in the SQL database, it is correct.  My problem was that my string had an unexpected single quote in it and it was causing the SQL command to fail.  When I started investigating, I focused on the VbCrlf because it looked wrong; I removed the single quote and the sting stored in the database correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use some combination of Char(10) and Char(13):

```
Dim strBody As String = "'Andy,'" & " + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + "
```

[There is a discussion about these and other methods on this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this if you just need to insert Environment.NewLine inside database.

```
Dim a As String = """ & Environment.NewLine & """
Dim strBody As String = String.Format("Andy,{0}", a)

'"Andy," & Environment.NewLine & ""
```