# SQL Server Line breaks ignored when copied from table

Tags: sql-server, line-breaks

I am putting new lines as `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`. But when copying the text from a table to text editor, new lines (line breaks) are ignored, and formatting is broken.

I want line breaks be preserved when copying from SSMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a line break in a SQL Server VARCHAR/NVARCHAR string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string)

Comment: There's an option in SSMS to remove / keep new lines when copying https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/06/03/sql-server-maintain-carriage-return-enter-key-ssms-2016-copy-paste/

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I now how to insert, as I wrote. I want to copy the value from SSMS editor WITH line breaks.

Comment: Which text editor are you copying the text to so I can replicate your issue?

Comment: @jamesZ You made it!!