# Textbox.Text new Line?

Tags: c#, string, newline

again a pretty simple question(i think so) but i can't find something via google. I think i'm using the wrong keywords but i don't know how to google it right.

So what i want to do is:
I have a text box (just a normal textbox not a richtextbox),
the input text is coming from a database.
Example String: "TextA \nTextB"

If i read out the string from the textbox the output is: "TextA \\nTextB".
I'm creating a pdf with the output from the textbox, so actual in the pdf you can read "TextA \nTextB", but there is no new line. If i create a normal string with "TextA \nTextB". I can see the new line in the pdf.

So basicly the question is:
What i have to change, that mit output string is the same as the input string?

What i already tried:
TextA \r\nTextB
TextA'\n'TextB
TextA"\n"TextB

Thank you

Comment: Environment.NEwLine..try that

Comment: I need to be very clear; does the string from the database contain a newline, or does it contain a slash and an n? Does `int i = theString[6]` come out as 10? or 92?

Comment: Environment.NewLine

Comment: Issues with newlines are notoriously difficult to diagnose just from *descriptions*, especially since e.g. what the *debugger* shows you is "what you would have to write in source code", not what the string actually "is". We could really do with some *code* to repro the issue, which hopefully can be done in a small sample without having to get the PDF side actually involved.

Comment: @MarcGravell actual it contains a slash n. but i can't change it to what ever i want

Comment: If it's winforms, the TextBox have a bool property called `Multiline`.if it's asp.net, the TextBox have a property called `TextMode`. If it's wpf, the TextBox have `AcceptsReturn` and `TextWrapping` properties...

Comment: Marc is saying that `\n` can be either a NewLine char (in SQL it's char(13)), or simplly a slash `\` followed by `n` (as in, two different chars). The first will cause a new line, the second will not. So which one is it in your case?

Comment: @ZoharPeled minor point: newline is 10; carriage return is 13

Comment: @MarcGravell it returns a 92

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for explaining this. I already tried the multiline flag, nothing changed

Comment: @TheRealLife a slash, then; yeah, that's simply not a newline in any way - it would be *incorrect* to represent it as a newline

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks! I always get them backwords. In fact, I'm so used to get them backwords that my first though was that it's 10 so I wrote 13 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(from comments)

> actual it contains a slash n

and

> it returns a 92

(where "it" is the character code at the index of the `...\n...`, so: a slash)

If the *contents* are a slash and an n, then: that isn't a newline, and the tools are doing the correct thing by representing it as a slash and an n. The `\n` syntax only applies to *C# literals*, as a way of telling the compiler to include something that *isn't* actually a slash and an n.

A C# literal expressed as `"foo\nbar"` is the string with contents:

```
foo
bar
```

(a newline)

However, a *string* with contents `foo\nbar` is *the string with contents*:

```
foo\nbar
```

(a slash and an n, no newlines)

For completeness, there's also C# *verbatim* string literals, expressed as `@"foo\nbar"` which is also the string with contents

```
foo\nbar
```

(a slash and an n, no newlines)

When you load a `string` value from the database, you aren't using C# literals - you are just dealing with strings. So a slash and an n means: a slash and an n. Not a newline.

So: if possible, store what you actually mean. The text in the database *should contain a newline*, not a slash and an n. If the line-breaks don't show *as line breaks* when you do `select TheValue from TheTable`, it isn't stored correctly.

If that isn't an option, you'll have to use some kind of text replace (maybe `.Replace(@"\r\n","\r\n").Replace(@"\n", "\n").Replace(@"\r", "\r")`), but you'll need to think about false positives, especially if your context can include things like code examples, i.e. slash followed by n is likely to appear to mean a slash followed by n.

---

In terms of SQL literals; if you wanted to do this in SQL, SQL literals *allow newlines directly*, so:

```
declare @someString nvarchar(200) = N'foo
bar'; -- this contains a newline
```

(although whether it contains CR, LF, CRLF or LFCR may depend on your editor's line-endings)

However, usually you would be populating values by SQL parameters, i.e.

```
cmd.CommandText = "... @val ..."; // some SQL
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", someStringThatHasNewlines);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

where `someStringThatHasNewlines` *contains newline characters* (ASCII 10/13), not slash+n.

Comment: And, of course, all of the problems that arise if you want to support double backslash meaning a literal backslash. (double backslash followed by n shouldn't produce a newline that naive replacement could cause)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I assume there you're talking about the last paragraph - the pain of trying to do a replace? If so, yeah, that's an important additional pain point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you example and your time. 
I tried to add a new line in the sql string. In this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string they are writing that i have to change my text to 'TextA' + CHAR(13) + 'TextB'. if I'm doing this. The text is exactly the same... So in my database give a this string back: "'TextA '+ CHAR(13)+ 'TextB'". I edited the database text directly via HeidiSQL. Was that wrong?

Comment: @TheRealLife I've added a note on SQL literals at the bottom of the post - impossible to format correctly in comments

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks a lot