# How to INSERT "multilined textbox" to 1 column in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a multilined `textbox` on my Winform. I want to `INSERT` it into my column in SQL Server. Does this automatically add the new lines into my column? Or is this even possible? BTW `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is the datatype of my column.

Comment: Yes just use the '.Text' property of the textbox

Answer (score 0):

The NVARCHAR(MAX) saves row breaks and should work with multilined textbox. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string) for an example.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `MAX`, any length `(n)(var)char` can store the characters for a Carriage Return (ASCII code 13) and a Line Break (ASCII code 10).

Answer (score 0):

It should be no different than any other text insert -- it's just that this text may (or may not) contain newline characters:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into MyTable (BigTestField) values (@TEXTBOX_DATA)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TEXTBOX_DATA", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = textbox.Text;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```