# Need to add line break in sql statement so that it displays accordingly in html

Tags: html, sql, angular

I need to add a line break before the work please

```
File type must be PDF, JPEG or PNG (max file size 20MB) Please provide English translation if the document is not in English or Chinese.
```

It should look like the following when it is rendered in html

```
File type must be PDF, JPEG or PNG (max file size 20MB) 
Please provide English translation if the document is not in English or Chinese.
```

I have tried the following in the insert statement

```
INSERT INTO #Temp_Language (OnScreenTextCode, English, Mandarin) 
Values
('common.file-type-info',       'File type must be PDF, JPEG or PNG (max file size 20MB) <br /> Please provide English translation if the document is not in English or Chinese.',   N'文件类型必须是PDF、JPEG或PNG（文件大小不超过20MB）文件如非英文或中文，请提供英文译本。')

INSERT INTO #Temp_Language (OnScreenTextCode, English, Mandarin) 
Values
('common.file-type-info',       'File type must be PDF, JPEG or PNG (max file size 20MB) \r\n Please provide English translation if the document is not in English or Chinese.',     N'文件类型必须是PDF、JPEG或PNG（文件大小不超过20MB）文件如非英文或中文，请提供英文译本。')

INSERT INTO #Temp_Language (OnScreenTextCode, English, Mandarin) 
Values
('common.file-type-info',       'File type must be PDF, JPEG or PNG (max file size 20MB)' + char(13) + 'Please provide English translation if the document is not in English or Chinese.',   N'文件类型必须是PDF、JPEG或PNG（文件大小不超过20MB）文件如非英文或中文，请提供英文译本。')
```

Comment: So how do you render it in HTML?

Comment: I am using it in my angular app with ngz-translate library.  Something like  <label translate>common.file-type-info</label>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a line break in a SQL Server VARCHAR/NVARCHAR string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string)

Comment: Then look at Angular's label's documentation or that of ngz-translate to find out how to pass raw HTML or let it render line breaks as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on Your HTML renderer - it should respect the "/br" tag You supplied.

But You can add the CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) as Enter directly to your texts - CHAR(13) = Carriage Return, CHAR(10) = Line Feed.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp_Language (OnScreenTextCode, English, Mandarin) 
Values
('common.file-type-info', 'line1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'line2', N'文件...')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me